# What does "Package or folder" refer to in the File transform task in a release pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task

I'm completely new to Azure DevOps Pipelines so if I'm doing something incorrectly I'd appreciate a nod in the right direction... I setup a build pipeline and that seems to be working, now I'm trying to setup a release pipeline in order to run tests, it's mostly based on Microsoft's documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops

Before running tests I need to transform a config file to replace some variables like access keys, usernames, etc. What I setup is what I have below but for the life of me I can't figure out what text box `Package or folder` refers to. The documentation is super helpful as you can imagine:

`File path to the package or a folder`

but what package or what folder is this referring to??? I've tried several different things but everything errors with

`##[error]Error: Nopackagefoundwithspecifiedpattern D:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip`

or pretty much whatever I specify for a value.

[image]

Comment: Hi @socalcheesehead. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could solve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The File Transform task supports the `.zip` files.

Test with the default File Transform task settings, I could reproduce this issue.

In Release pipeline, the file path could has one more node for the build artifacts .zip file.

The format example:

`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\{Source alias name}\{Artifacts name}\*.zip`

So you could try to set the `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/**/*.zip` in `Package Or folder` field

For example:

[image]

On the other hand, you can check the specific path in the `Release log -> Download Artifacts Step`.

[image]

`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory): D:\a\r1\a`

You could aslo use this specific  path in the task.

**Update:**

If your file is Project Folder, you refer to the following sample:

File structure：

[image]

Task Settings:

[image]

Note:You only need to assign to the **folder node**.

You could also select the folder path  via `...` option.

[image]

Comment: My build pipeline doesn't produce any artifacts that I'm aware of. In the log i can my .config getting copied. `Copying file from "d:\a\1\s\test\App.config to d:\a\1\s\test\Test.dll.config` and so i've tried to specify that location but i get the same error

Comment: This sent me down a different track. I added a `publish` and `download` task to my build pipeline and found that the files i expect/need aren't part of the artifact, my solution contains a web api project and several class library files but when the artifact is published only files from the web api project are included, not ones from the other projects, any ideas why this would be?

Comment: Hi @socalcheesehead.  `Package Or folder` represents the folder or package containing the target file. You do not need to specify a specific file path.  From the log you shared,  it seems that the log is  Build log instead of release log. The previous error message indicates that you are using this task in the release pipeline. You need to check the `Release Log`.

Comment: On the other hand, from your description, the release source is folder project. You could check my update.